# Tenured professor’s husband convicted of a drugs-trafficking felony – are there any career implications?

Tags: united-states, professorship, drugs

At the university I work at in the US, a tenured professor’s husband has been convicted of drugs trafficking. Would there be any likely (career) implications for the professor?

Obviously, their personal life will be affected, but is it likely to have implications otherwise?

Comment: Does the professor use the same professional name as the husband? Some use their maiden name which may help...

Comment: They use a different name, but the name of the husband is a pretty common name anyway - not a name that would stick out

Comment: What does this have to do with academia?  Is this boat programming?  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14470/what-is-the-boat-programming-meme-about

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the boat programming reference, but the question is definitely about academia. The question is asking whether there would be career consequences for a professor whose husband had been convicted of a felony. If the Professor herself had been convicted, I think the answer would be clear. In this case, the connection between the felony and the professor is less direct. However, the nature of the crime (compared to say, assaulting someone) makes the link a little stronger than it might otherwise be

Comment: you are innocent until proven guilty, so a "somewhat stronger link to a felony" still equals innocent.

Comment: I'll note that drug laws in the US are insane. People get charged with "drug trafficking felonies" when they are nothing more than addicts sharing drugs with friends. The jails/prisons are full of such people.

Comment: Your ‘assumption’ is a baseless accusation wrapped up to look pretty.

Comment: @MaartenBuis  Innocent *unless* proven guilty.

Comment: this may be better generalised (what are the effects on a employee instead of professor)  and asked on the workplace stack exchange, though the answers there will probably also be very vague due to the nature of the question

Answer (score 7):

This is a question which can only the respective university can answer. (I assume in my answer that the police has not proven involvement of the professor in the drug thing.)

Ideally (and most likely also by law, but you do not specify your location), husband and wife (or husband and husband, wife and wife) are treated as two separate people -- if one does a crime, it does not mean that both are involved. That the professor is not involved should also be the default assumption of the university unless the police proved otherwise.

Of course, people often talk and make decisions which are not backed up by the law. It may be of course that there are implications for the professor -- most likely, it's not explicitly said that they are connected to the drug thing.

For implications outside of the university, the same holds. Ideally, nobody treats the prof differently, but people sometimes do.

Comment: If you need security clearance of some sort (think nuclear physics) spouses might count though.